# Operação com Fatoriais Java

Tags: java

Alguém consegue fazer essa questão em Java?
Não tenho ideia de como fazer, sou iniciante ainda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Formato de entrada

Um inteiro x correspondente ao X da equação e um inteiro n indicando a
quantidade de termos da série, a entrada termina quando x = 0 e n = 0.

Formato de saída

Um número de ponto flutuante formatado com seis casas decimais.

Exemplos de:
 Entrada

2 5
2 4
4 5
0 0

Saída

1.454674
1.453968
2.834568

Comment: Exemplos de Entrada: 2 5 ---> saída: 1.454674

Comment: O que você já tentou até agora? Fatoriais são um conceito muito simples para o programa. Você realmente precisa quebrar esta pergunta em funções.

Answer (score 6):

Sendo `T` um dos termos da série em questão, dado genericamente por:

```
T = SINAL * (X ^ EXPOENTE)
            --------------
               DIVIDOR!
```

E considerando que:

- `SINAL` é um número que alterna entre os valores `1` ou `-1`, começando com `-1`
- `EXPOENTE` é uma sequência que inicia com `2` e vai incrementando de `2` em `2` até completar a operação (`2, 4, 6, ..., N`)
- `DIVISOR` é uma sequência que inicia com `3` e vai incrementando de `2` em `2` até completar a operação (`3, 5, 7, ..., N`)

E ainda que:

- `S` é  valor da soma atual
  e o seu valor inicial é `X`
- `S_ANTERIOR` é o valor da iteração anterior
- `X` é o valor digitado pelo usuário

Faça o seguinte:

1. Declare as variáveis para controlar os valores acima
2. Inicialize as variáveis com o valor inicial de cada uma delas
3. Faça um laço que:

   1. Calcule o valor de `T` como na função acima
   2. Salve o valor de `S` em `S_ANTERIOR` - `S_ANTERIOR = S`
   3. Some `S` com `T` - `S = S + T`
   4. Verifique a precisão do resultado.
      Isso pode ser feito verificando se `S - S_ANTERIOR  < 0.000001`, pois significa que todos os demais termos calculados não irão afetar as seis primeiras casas decimais da soma.

      - Se a condição for verdadeira, termine o laço.
      - Se a condição for falsa, calcula os próximos valores de `SINAL`, `EXPOENTE` e `DIVISOR` e volte ao início do laço (item 3.1)

O mais difícil para quem está começando em programação não é programar, mas entender o problema primeiro.

O que fiz acima foi descrever a lógica da implementação em termos de um algoritmo.

Sempre que você tiver um problema em mãos, a primeira coisa que precisa é entender como o problema é solucionado em formato de algoritmo, que nada mais é do que um conjunto de passos de chega ao resultado, em geral, de forma determinística ou iterativa.

Uma vez que você entender como o problema é resolvido, aí vem a parte de traduzir isto num programa.

Provavelmente você vai encontrar dificuldades específicas no decorrer da implementação, mas uma vez que você sabe o que quer, fica fácil encontrar a resposta.

Como receber o valor inicial, como declarar as variáveis e executar as operações matemáticas, todas estas são questões que você pode facilmente agora encontrar a resposta, afinal sabe exatamente qual pergunta fazer.

Comment: Muito didáctico. Um bom exemplo de como se deve/pode responder a este tipo de perguntas.

Comment: @utluiz `EXPOENTE` não seria incrementado de 2 em 2?

Comment: @hlucasfranca isso mesmo, já atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais ou menos isso:

```
public static int Fatorial(int num)  
{  
    if (num != 1) {  
        num *= Fatorial(num - 1);
    }  
   return num;  
}
```